# Duplicated selected state of UIButton inserted in UITableViewCell when Scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I select a `UIButton` in my `UITableViewCell` and it keep selected, Ive added one image per each state of the `UIButton` (through `Interface Builder`, not programmatically). But when I do scroll, the selected state appears duplicated. Ive read a lot of posts with similar information, but cant find the solution to my problem. I'm noticing that the `tableView` is reusing cells from cache with the state of the `UIButton`.

That's my code.

In my `Custom Cell`:

```
- (IBAction)highlightStar:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.starButton.selected=!sender.selected;
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` of my Controller:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellS"
                                bundle:nil];

   [self.tableView registerNib:nib
    forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of my Controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CellS *cell = (CellS *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    NSDictionary *dict=self.items[indexPath.row];

    NSString *header=[dict objectForKey:@"header"];

    [cell.labelReader setText:header];



    return cell;
}
```

Capture 1 (without Scroll). Two UIButtons selected:

[image]

Capture 2 (with Scroll). Two duplicated UIButton selected:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Changed my model, and every time I change the favourite state I change the model, and update the cells from the model.

In `cellForRotAtIndexPath`:

```
Model *new=nil;
//I parse the plist, and fill an array with Model Objects, where each Object is an item from the Plist. The method newsAtIndex returns the Model Object for the selected index   
new=[self.model newsAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.labelReader.text=new.header;
[cell.starButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapStarButton:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.starButton.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.starButton.selected=new.Favorite;
```

And in `didTapStarButton`:

```
Model *new=nil;
new=[self.model newsAtIndex:button.tag];
new.Favorite=button.selected;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since cells are getting reused during scrolling you also need to update button state before you return from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Custom Cell` class, add the following:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.starButton.selected= NO;
}
```

Also in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you should update the starButton state:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    SBQCell *cell = (SBQCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    NSDictionary *dict=self.items[indexPath.row];

    NSString *header=[dict objectForKey:@"header"];

    [cell.labelReader setText:header];

    // HERE - Update cell's starButton state according to your current data info
    cell.starButton.selected = [dict objectForKey:@"selectedState"];

    // Keep track of indexPath.row and add target
    cell.starButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.starButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapStarButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

That should do it.

**EDIT:** I added a way to keep track of your starButton's status in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  You need to add the following in your viewController:

```
- (void)didTapStarButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    // Here, keep track of the change in state with button.tag that is equal to the cell's indexPath.row

}
```

You can remove the code that change the starButton's status in your Custom Cell since you now do it here.

Comment: Thanks mate! I go quickly to try it and tell you something

Comment: But how can i get the indexPath of the row I touched from the Custom Cell class? Ive tried with CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];. I get self.tableView with a protocol method created in the Controller, but it doesn't recieved data. I set the delegate in the init method.

Comment: I have to change the data model in the Custom Cell, isnt it? Its where I change the state of the UIButtons. But how can I relate the BOOL state with the ROW from the Custom Cell?

Comment: I edited my code snippets to give you an example on how to keep track of the cell's indexPath when you use the starButton.

Comment: Please Rufel, could you see my new answer. Thanks and sorry for the apologizes ;(

Comment: @mikeShoma in `didTapStarButton` you get the value from self.items with `NSDictionary *dict=self.items[button.tag];` and set the boolean for the key "Favorite", but it's not clear if you put back that dictionary in self.items i.e. replace `self.items[button.tag]` with your updated dictionary.

Comment: If I do: [self.items[button.tag] setObject:boolSelected forKey:@"Favorite"]; when I scroll, the cells being empty and doesn't show any info

Comment: See my new solution, it is working. Thanks a lot for your help Rufel!